# C++ file input/output and array assistance

Tags: c++, arrays, file

I have a C++ project to do for my class and it's quite intricate, to me at least. I've got the general idea and concept down, but i'm running into some other problems when it comes to the arrays and file stuff. Below is what the project consists of

You will be building and modifying a class roster system for a Teacher to manage his class roster and their final grades. This program
will use functions for the various menu options, and you will work with
the data in arrays or vectors. The program will provide a menu system that allows for the teacher to perform tasks until he chooses to close the program. The program will read and write to a file called
classroster.txt. Any and all additions, deletions, or changes to the roster will be saved in classroster.txt file.
This file will contain the names of each of the students in the class with their grade. See the following for an example listed below of how the data would be stored in the classroster.txt file. You should work with the data using arrays or vectors.

```
Jim Jones C
Kevin James B
Marc Cohen A+
```

When the program starts it should read the data from the classroster.txt into arrays or vectors. While the program is running it should use the arrays or vectors for the functions while using the program. When the program ends it should overwrite the classroster.txt file if something has been changed. The
programs menu will offer the following options and will allow the user to keep performing functions until they choose to exit the program ( hint !!!!! you will need to use a loop for the menu system)

Add A New Student-
This will allow the user to add a new student to the system. The system should prompt for the new students full name and then grade.
It should validate that the grade is in the following values
(A+, A, A-, B+, B, B-,C+,C, C-, D+, D, D-, F) and if not
in the approved list it should prompt the user for a valid grade.

Change a Students Grade-
This will find the student in question and change the grade. If the specified student doesn’t exist the program should print an error message telling the user that you couldn’t find the specified student to
change their grade.

Remove a Student-
Will remove a student and their grade from the roster. If the specified student doesn’t exist the program should print an error message telling the user that you couldn’t find the specified student to remove.

Display Class Roster–
(Bonus Points if you can display the names is alphabetical order) This
function will display the list of all the students and their grades on
the screen that looks like this:

```
Student Name Grade
Jim Jones C
Kevin James B-
Marc Cohen A+
```

This is what i have so far, it's obviously not done yet

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    const int num_of_students;
    const int new_student = 1, change_grade = 2, remove_student = 3, display_roster = 4, quit = 5;
    int classroster[num_of_students];
    int student_grade[num_of_students];
    string possible_grades[13] = {"A+", "A", "A-", "B+", "B", "B-", "C+", "C", "C-", "D+", "D", "D-", "F"};
    int choice;
    ofstream class_file;


    cout << "How many students do you have in your class?" << endl;
    cin >> num_of_students;

    cout << "---MENU---" << endl;
    cout << "1. Add A New Student" << endl;
    cout << "2. Change A Students Grade" << endl;
    cout << "3. Remove A Student" << endl;
    cout << "4. Display Class Roster" << endl;
    cout << "5. Quit" << endl;
    cout << "Enter your choice: ";
    cin >> choice;

    if (choice == new_student) {
        for (int index = 0; index < num_of_students; index++) {
        class_file.open("classroster.txt");
        cout << "What is the name of the student you want to add? ";
        getline(cin, classroster);
        if (student_grade == possible_grades) {
        cout << "What is the final grade of this student? ";
        getline(cin, student_grade);
            }
        else {
                "Please enter a valid grade!"
            }
        cout << "Student added!";
        }
    }

    else if (choice == change_grade) {
        class_file.open("classroster.txt");
        cout << "What is the name of the student whose grade you want to change? ";
        getline(cin, )
    }

    else if (choice == remove_student) {

    }

    else if (choice == display_roster) {

    }

    else if (choice == quit) {

    }

    else {
        cout << "Please enter a valid choice!"
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You want us to fill in all the blanks?

Comment: oh no definitely not, i just want to know how to go about the rest of the problem.

Comment: *What* rest of the problem? What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: im having trouble where i will need to change a students grade, im assuming i will need a way to search an array and change the corresponding grade with the student?

Comment: This problem screams for a `std::map<string,string>`. I would ask if you could use a `map` rather than arrays. Using arrays makes no sense. You should also use `std::vector` rather an C-Style arrays.

Comment: i dont even know what that is unfortunately :(
we havent gone over that concept in class yet, plus my teacher wants us to use arrays or vectors.

Answer (score 0):

First, to answer your question, here's one way to search an array of student names:

```
int index = -1;

for(int k=0; k<num_of_students; ++k)
{
  if(names[k] == name)
    index = k;
}
```

And here's a way to change the array of grades:

```
student_grade[index] = 3;
```

More generally, you taking the wrong approach. Your code does not compile, so it looks as if you're writing it all out before testing any of it. As they never seem to teach in school, you should start with something small and simple, add complexity a little at a time, test at every step, and **never add to code that doesn't work.**

Let's start with the number of students:

```
int main() {
  const int num_of_students;
  cout << "How many students do you have in your class?" << endl;
  cin >> num_of_students;
  return(0);
}
```

Try to compile this, and you'll find that there's something wrong. Fix it and try constructing an array of int and filling it in. Once that's working, try an array of `string`. Small steps.

Comment: thanks for the first part of code! A question though, why did you assign student_grade[index] = 3?

also, i keep getting an error with that last part of code of something about binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::istream'

Comment: @user3085052: That's the way to change that element of the array to 3 (which I suppose corresponds to changing some student's grade to B+). Once you have that working, you can replace the 3 with a variable like `new_grade`. As for the trouble with `cin`, you should experiment with `cin` by itself, in the simplest program you can write that uses it. Once you have it working, **save that program**; it will be a part of your toolbox, your bag of tricks, so that any time you have a problem with `cin` you can reach for your working example.

Answer (score 0):

You realy should be using maps for this question, its makes the most sense. Here is code to read in the map from a file. After you have the map all the operations you need are already implemented in the STL. I realize you may need to use `vector` but I'd like to think you wouldn't be penalized for being clever and actually writing a proper solution.

```
#include <map>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    map<string,string> data;

    fstream fs("classroster.txt");

    while(fs.good()){
        string fname, lname, grade;
        fs >> fname;
        fs >> lname
        fs >> grade;
        fname += lname; //Concat Names to get full
        if(grade == "A") //Check other grades as well.
            data.emplace(fname,grade);

    }

    while(1){
        string option;
        std::cout << "Options:" << endl;
        cin >> option;
        //Your option selection code here

    }
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:
`map`s are also sorted by key name so printing alphabetically is very easy, no sorting required.

```
for(auto& pairs : data)
    cout << pairs.first << " " << pairs.second << endl;
```

Comment: thanks for your time to try and help me with my problem, but unfortunately i just do not understand whats going on here :(